# Verilog conditional assign outputs X where there should be 1

Tags: output, verilog, assign

I am currently building a sign extender in Verilog based on the one present in the ARMv8 processor, but after the first result is extended, every subsequent result makes a 1 in the output into an X.  How do I get rid of the X?

The module and the quick test bench I made are shown below.

Sign Extender:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module SignExtender(BusImm, ImmIns); 
  output [63:0] BusImm; 
  input [31:0] ImmIns; 
  wire extBit;
  
  assign extBit = (ImmIns[31:26] == 6'bx00101) ? ImmIns[25]:
                  (ImmIns[31:24] == 8'bxxx10100) ? ImmIns[23]:
                  (ImmIns[31:21] == 11'bxxxx1000xx0) ? ImmIns[20]:
                                                       1'b0;
  
  assign BusImm = (ImmIns[31:26] == 6'bx00101) ? {{38{extBit}}, ImmIns[25:0]}:
                  (ImmIns[31:24] == 8'bxxx10100) ? {{45{extBit}}, ImmIns[23:5]}:
                  (ImmIns[31:21] == 11'bxxxx1000xx0) ? {{55{extBit}}, ImmIns[20:12]}:
                                                                               64'b0;
  assign BusImm = 64'b0;
endmodule
```

Test Bench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

`define STRLEN 32
`define HalfClockPeriod 60
`define ClockPeriod `HalfClockPeriod * 2

module SignExtenderTest;

    task passTest;
        input [63:0] actualOut, expectedOut;
        input [`STRLEN*8:0] testType;
        inout [7:0]       passed;

        if(actualOut == expectedOut) begin $display ("%s passed", testType); passed = passed + 1; end
        else $display ("%s failed: 0x%x should be 0x%x", testType, actualOut, expectedOut);
    endtask

    task allPassed;
        input [7:0] passed;
        input [7:0] numTests;

        if(passed == numTests) $display ("All tests passed");
        else $display("Some tests failed: %d of %d passed", passed, numTests);
    endtask
    
    reg [7:0]  passed;
    reg [31:0] in;
    wire [63:0] out;
    
    SignExtender uut (
    .BusImm(out),
    .ImmIns(in)
    );
    
    
    initial begin
        passed = 0;
        in = 32'hF84003E9;
    #10;
    begin
    passTest(out, 63'b0, "Stuff", passed);
    #10;
    in = 32'hf84093ea;
    #10;
    passTest(out, 63'b0, "Stuff", passed);
    end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Im using the x's as dont cares in my comparison, should I use a different character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be treating `x` as a "don't-care" value in your comparisons, but it is not.  `x` is a specific value which represents "unknown".  Since you drive your input signals to all known values (0 or 1), all your `==` comparisons resolve to `x`, and your output has `x` in it.  You should only compare bits you are interested in.  For example, change:

```
              (ImmIns[31:21] == 11'bxxxx1000xx0) ? {{55{extBit}}, ImmIns[20:12]}:
```

to:

```
              ( (ImmIns[27:24] == 4'b1000) && (ImmIns[21] == 1'b0) ) ? {{55{extBit}}, ImmIns[20:12]}:
```

You need to make similar changes to all your comparisons.

Also, you drive `BusImm` with 2 continuous assignments.  Get rid of this line:

```
assign BusImm = 64'b0;
```

These changes get the `x` out of your output.

---

Also consider using `casez`.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 12.5.1 *Case statement with do-not-cares*.